# Why can't GHC deduce type equality on a class type family in a Rank 2 type?

Tags: haskell, type-constraints, type-families, higher-rank-types

As a very trimmed-down version of what I'm experiencing:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
class ValueGen v where
  type Output v
  generate :: v -> Output v

instance ValueGen Integer where
  type Output (Integer) = Integer
  generate n = n + 1

newtype IntGenerator = Gen { generator :: forall v. ValueGen v => ((Output v) ~ Integer) => v }

myGen :: IntGenerator
myGen = Gen (3 :: Integer)
```

The error that GHC gives is

```
Could not deduce: v ~ Integer
from the context: (ValueGen v, Output v ~ Integer)
  bound by a type expected by the context:
            forall v. (ValueGen v, Output v ~ Integer) => v
```

This works fine if I just try to restrict `v` by type equality.

What is the issue that GHC is encountering? Why is it trying to deduce the restriction `v ~ Integer` if that's already informed by the typing of `3 :: Integer`? Shouldn't the restriction check be that `Output Integer`, which resolves to `Integer`, is equal to `Integer`, and then pass?

#### Abstract

I hit this trying to write a rank 2 type which contained two `Pipeline` class instances which share some intermediate type. The essential idea was to get two pipelines like

```
a|---|b  b|---|c
```

and produce a new type `Joined` which is then an instance of `Pipeline`

```
a|------------|c
a|---|b  b|---|c
```

The issue is that the inner pipelines are stored with internal `forall`s using a restriction of type equality to a type parameter of `Joined` - but GHC seems to not recognise when the restriction is satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition you have written means that for `IntGenorator` you have:

> If you give me an `IntGenorator` and think of some type `v` such that `Output v ~ Integer` then I will give you something of type `v` based on whatever is inside the `IntGenorator`
>
> If for any type `v` such that `Output v ~ Integer`, you can give me something of type `v` then you can construct something of type `IntGenorator`

Because the type family is not injective there could be other types `v` than `Integer` such that `Output v ~ Integer` (note they could be in modules which ghc hasn’t compiled yet or which haven’t been written yet). Therefore ghc cant prove that the only type `v` with `Output v ~ Integer` is `Integer` (or rather some set of types which implement `Num`) and that therefore `3 :: Integer` (or rather `3 :: Num a => a`) is a valid value of the type `forall v. (Output v ~ Integer) => v`.

E.g. what if someone added an instance `ValueGen Char` with `Output Char = Integer`. Then `3` is certainly not of type `Char` (unless one implements `Num Char`) so you can’t put it inside an `IntGenerator`

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the restriction of being able to determine the field type as any type which fit the equality check. What's the solution for `IntGenerator` to be able to hold any instance of the class, then - make `v` a type parameter?

Comment: I suspect you meant `data IntGenerator where Gen :: forall v. (ValueGen v, Output v ~ Integer) => { generator :: v } -> IntGenerator`

Comment: That is precisely what I was thinking of!